# How to transform Duplicate Object (Ctrl+D) into Linked Duplicate (Alt+D)

Tags: linked-data, duplicate

I have some trees that I did **Transform to Mesh** and **Apply All Transform** (to post on the Website). Now how can I transform these *Objects back to Linked Duplicate* ?? I know that I can **Link (Ctrl+L) --> Object Data**, but it will automatically transform Scale & Rotation. How can I make them Linked Duplicate but keep Scale & Rotation ??

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

**TL,DR:**

If you want to keep the transforms, do not apply them before linking.

**Detailed explanation:**

There is a misunderstanding on your behalf. The *Scale* and *Rotation* (and *Location*) are not automatically transformed when you link one object to another.

See the following example. The cube has the following transforms:

- Location: (2.5 m, 5.5 m, 2m)
- Rotation: (65°, -40°, 15°)
- Scale: (2, 2, 2)

[image: transformed cube]

The cylinder has all values 0 (*Location/Rotation*) resp. 1 (*Scale*). If I now use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd> > *Link Object Data* to link the cube object to the cylinder, this is what happens (I've selected the former cube again as active object so you can see the values):

[image: linked to cylinder]

As you can see, there is now a cylinder instead of a cube, but this cylinder has the same location, rotation and scale as the cube beforehand.

But what happens if - before linking - you **Apply All Transforms** like you did as you said in the question (but I only applied *Rotation* and *Scale*, otherwise the cube's origin point would have moved to the world center)? The cube looks like before, but now the *Rotation* is 0° on all axes and the *Scale* is 1. This is what applying the transforms does: it leaves the transformations of an object as they are and resets the values to make this the new "original state" of the object:

[image: applied transforms on cube]

And then happens exactly what you experienced: because the transformations are **not linked**, the cube gets the mesh data from the cylinder and how it would look like if set to the transformations of the cube - but they are no longer rotated or scaled, so the new cylinder has the base size and no rotation.

[image: linked data in original state]

The former cube has not been given the scale and rotation of the cylinder - it has kept the (applied) transforms like before, and with these transforms the new cylinder looks like the old, since this is what the cylinder looks like not rotated and scaled to 1.

Now, because applying *Scale* and *Rotation* resets the values while keeping the mesh transformed and they are not stored anywhere - how should they be brought back when linking objects? Which means, the simple answer to your question is: *Do not apply transforms if you want to keep them.*

Comment: I know what Apply for All means. Like I said, I apply because I want to use them on Websites and other Software. So your answer "Do not apply transforms if you want to keep them" is not the answer (It's an advice, which not help in my case). I want to know IF I ALREADY APPLY, is there any way to recover it ??

Comment: @Iampoor 1. Sorry that I explained what apply all transforms means, you said the linking  would change the transform which is plain wrong so it was not obvious you know how it works. 2. Others might not know and this site aims at being a knowledge database for others with similar problems, so it can still be helpful information. 3. And I answered the question if there is a way to recover it (apart from Ctrl+Z), and the answer is simply: no. As I said, the information is not stored anywhere, so how should it be recovered? That's why applying modifiers is called a "destructive workflow".

Comment: @Iampoor It is similar in software like Photoshop: when I edit a photo by compositing it from different elements in different layers and with adjustment layers etc., I have to save it in a format which supports these layers (usually the software's own format) if I want to edit it again later. When I want to upload it somewhere else like Facebook or Instagram I have to merge all layers into a single one and save as JPG or PNG for example - but I usually do this with a copy to keep the editable file. If not, I do not have to wonder why I cannot get my adjustment layers back from the JPG.

Comment: So the answer is "Impossible to Reconstruct". OK, thanks for your explanation. I still hope that I can find a way to work around it. But thanks

Comment: @Iampoor No, I am sorry, not really reconstructable. It is often a problem when people try to export something for game engines etc., as all softwares Blender has some features which are not supported or somehow transferable to other software (which is why you have to apply things most of the times). So when you do this to get your project opened or uploaded somewhere else, it is always best to save a fully editable version of it as Blender file. Depending on what you did, is there maybe a backup file saved somewhere from before applying the transforms?

Comment: No, I don't save the backup file for Blender, this is why I ask this question. I can remake the tree by hand, but there are thousands of grass objects. And it's impossible to make it exactly. I am still finding the automatic way.